# How do I sum up multiple fields of a class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a class Dimensions(Int, Int, Int) and a Shape(String name), put into a Tuple(Shape, Dimensions)

My dataset is:

```
(Cube, Dimensions(5,5,5))
(Sphere, Dimensions(5,10,15))
(Cube, Dimensions(3,3,3))
```

I need to return this:

```
(Cube, Dimensions(8,8,8))
(Sphere, Dimensions(5,10,15))
```

where I group by the name of the shape then sum up all of the dimension values. Currently I am able to map into a (Name, Int, Int, Int) but I am unsure of how to wrap it back to a Dimension object.

```
data.map(_._2.map(x => (x.length,x.width,x.height)))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do we have `apache-spark` tag on this question ? Are you doing this on Spark ? The efficient answer to this will depend on how huge this dataset is and just how many unique Shapes are there.

Comment: yes, on an RDD but using Scala

Comment: RDD or DataSet or DataFrame ?

Comment: There are around 1000 unique shapes, the RDD has 10000 lines

Comment: Dataset or RDD ? These are not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no very specific special cases and you have a RDD. You just need an `aggregateByKey`.

```scala
case class Dimensions(i1: Int, i2: Int, i3: Int)

val initialRdd: RDD[(Shape, Dimensions)] = ???

def combineDimensions(dimensions1: Dimensions, dimensions2: Dimensions): Dimensions =
  Dimensions(
    dimensions1.i1 + dimensions2.i1,
    dimensions1.i2 + dimensions2.i2,
    dimensions1.i3 + dimensions2.i3
  )

val finalRdd: RDD[(Shape, Dimensions)] =
  initialRdd
    .aggregateByKey(Dimensions(0, 0, 0))(
      { case (accDimensions, dimensions) =>
        combineDimensions(accDimensions, dimensions)
      },
      { case (partitionDimensions1, partitionDimensions2) =>
        combineDimensions(partitionDimensions1, partitionDimensions1)
      }
    )
```

Comment: thanks, this worked! may I know why do you do 2 cases?

Comment: becuase `aggregateByKey` take two functions as parameters. first function for aggregating the values inside each of the partitions. second function for aggreating the "partition aggregate" values. Both of these functions take the tuple `t` (which is made of `(currentAggregate, currentValue)`) as argument, so we are using pattern matching to deconstruct that tuple and directly define our function in terms of `currentAggregate`, `currentValue` instead of tuple components `t._1` and `t._2`. The same functions could have been written as `t => combineDimensions(t._1, t._2)` as well.